# validator plugin error is visible on startup

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validator plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) with asp.net application.
Here is my from elements:

```
<input id="chbConfirmDetails" type="checkbox" runat="server" class="required" />
<br />
<label for="<%=chbConfirmDetails.ClientID %>" class="alert">Please select this checkbox.</label>
```

The probelm is that the label with the error is visible on startup instead of hidden.
I can add a class to hide the label but shouldn't the validator plugin take care of that?

Why the error is not hidden?

**UPDATE:**
I explicit add the label because I want the error message to be placed in a specific position and not right after the input.

Comment: You shouldn't hardcode error labels - they're added by the script on submit.

Comment: @jfrej: This is a sample to cases where I want to put the label in specific position and not right after the input.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to add *any* explicit markup for your validation message: the plugin takes care of generating it when errors occur.  So the input field alone should be all you need:

```
<input id="chbConfirmDetails" type="checkbox" runat="server" class="required" />
```

When you configure validation, you have control over how the plugin generates error markup - to add the 'alert' class, you'll need to ensure it's set in your call to `.validate()`, e.g:

```
$("form").validate({
   errorClass: "alert"
})
```

Comment: This is a sample to cases where I want to put the label in specific position and not right after the input.

Comment: As @Sudhir mentions in his revised answer, you should override the `errorPlacement` option to control where in the DOM an error message is placed.  If you need _really_ fine-grained control over how error messages are rendered, then you can also pass through a custom `showErrors` function.

Comment: errorPlacement according to documentation is: "Customize placement of created error labels." I want to customize a placement for a single error label. According to documentation: "Error messages are handled via label elements with an additional class (option errorClass). The link between the message and the invalid element is provided via the label's for attribute. **When provided in the markup, they are shown and hidden accordingly**, otherwise created on demand."

Comment: Ok. There doesn't seem to be lot of information in the documentation regarding it, but I think: (1) you need to hide the error message by default: it doesn't look like the plugin retrieves existing error messages on startup; and (2) because you're validating a checkbox, it looks like your label should have the element's name, not the id, in the 'for' attribute.  In the implementation of `showLabel`, the plugin builds the label like this `.attr({"for":  this.idOrName(element)})`, where the implementation of idOrName returns the element's name for radio/checkbox elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove this line:

```
<label for="<%=chbConfirmDetails.ClientID %>" class="alert">Please select this checkbox.</label>
```

The validator plugin itself appends error label on validation returning false with some class specified.

You need to dd a custom errorPlacement callback to place the error message, for example

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.type == 'checkbox') {
                error.insertAfter(element); //something like this, just an example
            }
            else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
```